# MySQL group by issue: incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql

Task: Show per shop the most bought product.
3 tables: shop, product, payment. If there is a tie on products that are sold to 1 shop, it doesn't matter which product gets picked, it just have to pick one of them.

I have an issue with a group by clause on this query:

```
SELECT shop_id, product_id, 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM payment 
  WHERE product.product_id = payment.product_id
) sold
FROM product
GROUP BY shop_id
HAVING MAX(sold)
```

In MySQL 5.6 or lower this query would work.
This will be the result which is correct:

```
shop_id | product_id | sold
1         1            3
2         3            1
3         5            1
```

But on 5.7 I'm getting the incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by, because product_id in the select contains non-aggregated data.

Full Error message:

```
Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'product.product_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

So the solution I thought would be adding the product_id in the group by like so:

```
SELECT shop_id, product_id, 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM payment 
  WHERE product.product_id = payment.product_id
) sold
FROM product
GROUP BY shop_id, product_id
HAVING MAX(sold)
```

That fixes the error but that returns the wrong result, it does not make the shop column unique anymore. I'm getting this:

```
shop_id | product_id | sold
1         1            3
1         2            4
2         3            1
2         4            1
3         5            1
```

SQLfiddle uses MySQL 5.6 but to make everybody's life easier:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca12bf9/6

Comment: what's not clear is why you are using the payment table here

Comment: @e4c5 1 payment has 1 product, 1 product has 0..N payments made to it. Each row in the payment table represents a sold product, so that's why I'm doing a COUNT on it so I know how many times a particular product has been sold.

Comment: I'm not sure the original results are correct either, because from the raw data it looks like shop_id 2 sold 1 each of products 3 and 4. How do you want ties handled? It's something that should be considered.

Comment: @CGritton Ties doesn't matter, sorry I forgot to include that. If there is a tie it can choose the first row or a random one, but one has to be picked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirement is surprisingly complex. That you got a useful result from MySQL's nonstandard extension to `GROUP BY` is **entirely accidental.** Results based on that extension resemble nothing so much as a talking donkey. It's not amazing it works badly, it's amazing it works at all.

Here's what you have to do.

(1) summarize sales by product and shop. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca12bf9/12/0)

```
                   select product.product_id, product.shop_id, count(*) sale_count
                     from product
                     join payment on product.product_id = payment.product_id
                    group by product.product_id, product.shop_id
```

(2) find the number of units sold for the best-selling product in each shop, by summarizing (1)  (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca12bf9/13/0)

```
     SELECT MAX(sale_count) max_sale_count, shop_id
       FROM (
                   select product.product_id, product.shop_id, count(*) sale_count
                     from product
                     join payment on product.product_id = payment.product_id
                    group by product.product_id, product.shop_id
                 ) findmax
       GROUP BY shop_id
```

(3) Join (1) to (2) to retrieve the identity of the product or products that sold the most in each shop.  (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca12bf9/11/0)

```
SELECT a.product_id, a.shop_id, b.max_sale_count
  FROM (
            select product.product_id, product.shop_id, count(*) sale_count
              from product
              join payment on product.product_id = payment.product_id
             group by product.product_id, product.shop_id    
       ) a
  JOIN (
         SELECT MAX(sale_count) max_sale_count, shop_id
                FROM (
                       select product.product_id, product.shop_id, count(*) sale_count
                         from product
                         join payment on product.product_id = payment.product_id
                        group by product.product_id, product.shop_id
                     ) findmax
               GROUP BY shop_id
       ) b ON a.shop_id = b.shop_id AND a.sale_count = b.max_sale_count
```

The data you provided has a tie. So two different products show up as best sellers in one of your shops.

It's this kind of query that puts the *structured* in *structured query language.*.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can set sql_mode to blank
by set `sql_mode ='' in my.ini`

or you can use `ANY_VALUE(product_id)`

while using non-aggregate column with group by never guarantee what will be the outcome.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value

**update 1** : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Thanks, the ANY_VALUE does work. But surely there must be a way to solve this issue without ANY_VALUE or changing the sql mode?

Comment: in the previous versions of mysql, mysql implicitly do the same behavior as the function introduced in 5.7, you can check more on updated answer